# Urlhelper and IActionContextAccessor in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, urlhelper

I have some .net framework 4.5 code that I'd like to transpose to .net core :

```
[DataContract]
    public class RouteData
    {
        public RouteData()
        {
            Request = new RequestRouteData();
        }

        [DataMember] public RequestRouteData Request { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestRouteData : BaseRouteData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string AddUploadOtherFileStep5
        {
            get { return UrlHelper.Action("AddOtherFields", "Request"); }
        }
    }


    public class BaseRouteData
    {
        protected UrlHelper UrlHelper { get; set; }

        protected BaseRouteData()
        {
            UrlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        }
    }
```

So, I found out that to get the current context I have to use `IActionContextAccessor` bu I'm struggling getting the equivalent methods to do so.

Here is what I tried so far :

```
[DataContract]
    public class RouteData
    {
        public RouteData()
        {
            Request = new RequestRouteData();
        }

        [DataMember] public RequestRouteData Request { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestRouteData : BaseRouteData()
    {
        [DataMember] public string AddOtherFields => UrlHelper.Action(What to put here?);
    }


    public class BaseRouteData
    {
        protected UrlHelper UrlHelper { get; }

        protected BaseRouteData(IActionContextAccessor actionContext, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory)
    {
        UrlHelper = (UrlHelper) urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext.ActionContext);
    }
    }
```

EDIT 3 :

```
public class JavascriptData
    {
        public JavascriptData()
        {
            Routes = new RouteData();
        }

        [DataMember] public RouteData Routes { get; set; }

        #region ScriptFactory

        public static string ScriptFactory()
        {
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            var script = new StringBuilder();
            JavascriptData appData = new JavascriptData();
            var text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appData, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);
            script.AppendFormat("var appData={0}", text);
            return script.ToString();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Am I heading right? Because I don't know what to do with the `UrlHelper.Action()` method to get the same result as in .net 4.5...

Answer (score 2):

Almost. You need to inject `IUrlHelperFactory` as well. Then:

```
UrlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext.ActionContext);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time Chris. I modified my code to inject the `IUrlHelperFactory` as you mentionned. Still, I don't know how to get the equivalent to the old `UrlHelper.Action("AddOtherFields", "Request");`. Any clue?

Comment: What's the issue once you have your UrlHelper instance?

Comment: well, the issue is that the UrlHelper instance seems to always be `null`

Comment: How are you ultimately using this? You must be within the request pipeline or `ActionContext` will be null. If you're hoping to be able to generate URLs outside of a request, that's not technically possible. There's `LinkGenerator` in 2.1, but its functionality is very limited currently.

Comment: Oh, well, that's may be why it's always null, then. I just added a print to the second post of what the company use to have with the original code i'm trying to transpose to .net core

Comment: Assuming you're generating this in an action that returns that JSON, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I may have found how to do so. If aanyone can confirm I am doing right it would be verry appreciated :)

In `Startup.cs` I added :

```
services.AddScoped(sp => {
                var actionContext = sp.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
                var urlHelperFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
                return urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
            });
```

then my `RouteData.cs` becomes :

```
     [DataContract]
        public class RouteData
        {
            public RouteData(IUrlHelper iUrlHelper)
            {
                Request = new RequestRouteData(iUrlHelper);
            }
            [DataMember] public RequestRouteData Request { get; set; }
        }

        public class RequestRouteData : BaseRouteData
        {
            public RequestRouteData(IUrlHelper iUrlHelper) : base(iUrlHelper)
            {
            }
            [DataMember] 
public string AddOtherFields => UrlHelper.Action("AddOtherFields", "Request");
        }


        public class BaseRouteData
        {
            protected UrlHelper UrlHelper { get; }
            protected BaseRouteData(IUrlHelper iUrlHelper)
            {
                UrlHelper = iUrlHelper as UrlHelper;
            }
        }
```

and the Javascriptdata() :

```
[DataContract]
    public class JavascriptData
    {
        private static IUrlHelper _iUrlHelper;
        public JavascriptData(IUrlHelper iUrlHelper)
        {
            _iUrlHelper = iUrlHelper;
            Routes = new RouteData(_iUrlHelper);
        }

        [DataMember] public RouteData Routes { get; set; }

        #region ScriptFactory

        public static string ScriptFactory()
        {
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            var script = new StringBuilder();
            JavascriptData appData = new JavascriptData(_iUrlHelper);
            var text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appData, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);
            script.AppendFormat("var appData={0}", text);
            return script.ToString();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The end goal is to generate a json at the start of the application, that could be used by the front dev team in their ajax etc.. it's something they used to have and i'm trying to transpose to .net core.

here is an example :

[image]

Comment: Well, I thought it was good but I keep getting this error when building :   `RouteData.cs(20, 50): [CS1003] Syntax error, ',' expected` wich is located on the `public class RequestRouteData : BaseRouteData()  { ... }`

Comment: How did you want to use with `RouteData`? Share us the related code, you need to define constructor which accepts `IUrlHelper ` for `RequestRouteData` and remove `()` in `public class RequestRouteData : BaseRouteData()`

Comment: @TaoZhou Sorry for not giving an answer ealier, just got stuck home with the flu. I updated the original post so you can see where it will be use. The goal is to create routes an serialize them to create a json that will be accessible for the front dev team.

Comment: @TaoZhou but if I create a constructor for RequestRoutedata() that accepts IUrlHelper, I'll have to inject the IUrlHelper in RouteData() constructor as well, right? Then in my JavascriptData() constructor...? Just edited the post above to share the advancement...